# Discord Random Link Sender

Tags: javascript, discord

Client Unexpected identifier error atm.
I get a value/variable not specified (valueToUse is not defined).
I've spent the last 4 hours mind-boggled by this.

I've tried switching brackets, cutting down the number of links I use

```
});
function test () {

var values = [], the links normally go here but it hurt my head 
valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length
)
     client.on('message', msg =>{
     if (msg.content === "FFS")
     msg.send`??? ${valueToUse}` should send 3 question minds and the link/image from the link
   })};
```

Sends a random link out of the lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('message', msg =>{
    if (msg.content === "FFS"){
        var values = [];
        var valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
        msg.send(`??? ${valueToUse}`);
    }
});
```

This should work. YOU ARE DEFINING VALUE TO USE OUTSIDE OF THE MESSAGE CHECK. Furthermore your code has a lot of errors.